# Glide downloading image again and again on Scroll with PageKeyedDataSource

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using pagination library of *Android Architecture Components* named of *PageKeyedDataSource*. I have infinite scrolling all working good for pagination expect images are loading again and again (which are already loaded)while scroll to top using *Glide*.

This is my code:

```
public class ItemDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, InspirationData> {

//the size of a page that we want
private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;

String userid = "";
String deviceId = "";

@Override
public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<Integer, InspirationData> callback) {

    userid = SharedPreferencesUtils.getUserId(TrendiiApp.trendiiApp.getApplicationContext());

    if (userid.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        deviceId = Util.getDeviceid(TrendiiApp.trendiiApp.getApplicationContext());
    }


    RetrofitClient.getInstance()
            .getApi().getInspirations(userid, deviceId, FIRST_PAGE)
            .enqueue(new Callback<MainInspirationResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MainInspirationResponse> call, Response<MainInspirationResponse> response) {
                    Log.v("TSTSTSTS", userid + " : " + deviceId + " : " + FIRST_PAGE);
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        callback.onResult(response.body().getInspirationDataList(), null, FIRST_PAGE + 1);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MainInspirationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("EOROROROR", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
}

//this will load the previous page
@Override
public void loadBefore(@NonNull final LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadCallback<Integer, InspirationData> callback) {
    userid = SharedPreferencesUtils.getUserId(TrendiiApp.trendiiApp.getApplicationContext());

    if (userid.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        deviceId = Util.getDeviceid(TrendiiApp.trendiiApp.getApplicationContext());
    }

    RetrofitClient.getInstance()
            .getApi().getInspirations(userid, deviceId, FIRST_PAGE)
            .enqueue(new Callback<MainInspirationResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MainInspirationResponse> call, Response<MainInspirationResponse> response) {


                    Integer adjacentKey = (params.key > 1) ? params.key - 1 : null;
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        callback.onResult(response.body().getInspirationDataList(), adjacentKey);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MainInspirationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("EOROROROR", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
}

//this will load the next page
@Override
public void loadAfter(@NonNull final LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadCallback<Integer, InspirationData> callback) {
    userid = SharedPreferencesUtils.getUserId(TrendiiApp.trendiiApp.getApplicationContext());

    if (userid.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        deviceId = Util.getDeviceid(TrendiiApp.trendiiApp.getApplicationContext());
    }

    RetrofitClient.getInstance()
            .getApi().getInspirations(userid, deviceId, params.key)
            .enqueue(new Callback<MainInspirationResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MainInspirationResponse> call, Response<MainInspirationResponse> response) {

                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Integer key = params.key + 1;
                        ExtraInfo extraInfo = response.body().getExtraInfo();
                        if (extraInfo.getTotalpages() != key) {
                            callback.onResult(response.body().getInspirationDataList(), key);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MainInspirationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("EOROROROR", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
}
```

**Code for Image Loading:**

```
 public static void displayImage(final Activity activity, final String url, final ImageView imageView) {

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();

    requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
    requestOptions.dontAnimate();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.imge_placeholder);
    requestOptions.error(R.drawable.imge_placeholder);
    requestOptions.dontTransform();
    requestOptions.encodeFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG);
    requestOptions.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);


    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(url)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

`DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` is also not working. 
Any advanced help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
requestOptions.skipMemoryCache(false)
```